# Why am I able to ping my local device only sometimes?

Tags: linux, networking, ping

I have two Linux devices, `hostname1` and `hostname2` both are on the same wifi network. Both can ping the outside internet checked with `ping 8.8.8.8`. However when I try to ping `hostname2` from `hostname1` like `ping hostname2.local` I get the error of "Name or service not known". However this has worked at times, it seems to not work randomly. Neither device is running a firewall as far as I can tell. What should I check to debug this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check your configuration regarding converting between hostname hostname2.local to IP ; Check whether this service is running when "Name or service not known" is thrown ; Check whether IP is correctly matching the hostname to Ping !

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue, the problem seems to be due to mDNS (Avahi) not working correctly. Following this answer seemed to do the trick: https://askubuntu.com/a/460449/790690

Comment: My Earlier Comment was **Directing** you towards this type of Issue !